# Rails 6 / Kubernetes : Readiness HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 403

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm working on the setup of a new Rails project, hosted with Google Kubernetes Engine. Everything was going fine until I switched my deployed server to production mode, with `RAILS_ENV=production`.

My Kubernetes pods don't reach the ready state anymore. The readiness probe is forbidden to hit the server apparently, since it return a 403 code.

When I run `kubectl describe pod <name>` on a stuck pod, I get this :

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  5m25s                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned front to gke-interne-pool
  Normal   Pulling    5m24s                 kubelet            Pulling image "registry/image:latest"
  Normal   Pulled     5m24s                 kubelet            Successfully pulled image "registry/image:latest"
  Normal   Created    5m24s                 kubelet            Created container front
  Normal   Started    5m24s                 kubelet            Started container front
  Warning  Unhealthy  11s (x19 over 4m41s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 403
```

The return of `kubectl logs <name>` for this pod shows indeed no request from the probe.

But when I launch a console with `kubectl exec -it deploy/front -- bash`, I can make a `curl -s http://localhost:3000`, which works perfectly, is displayed in the logs and returns 200.

My setup works in development mode but not in production, and so the Rails 6 app config is the main suspect. Something that I don't understand in the production mode of Rails 6 forbid my readiness probes to contact my pod.

Just in case, the readiness part of deployment.yaml :

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: front
      image: registry/image:latest
      ports:
      - containerPort: 3000
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: "/"
          port: 3000
        initialDelaySeconds: 30
        periodSeconds: 15
```

Answer (score 4):

Another potential cause of readiness 403 errors with Rails 6 is the allowed hosts list defined in config.

Typically, you'll have a line of code in `config/environments/production.rb` that looks something like:

```rb
config.hosts << "www.mydomain.com"
```

This leads to the rejection of any requests that come from hosts other than "www.mydomain.com". The readiness checks come from a private IP address within your cluster so they're going to be rejected given the above config.

One way to get around this is by adding an additional hosts entry that allows traffic from any private IP addresses:

```rb
config.hosts << "www.mydomain.com"
config.hosts << /\A10\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\z/
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't notice a specific error whereby your implementation failed after switching the mode `RAILS_ENV = production`. But after checking the error 403 I was able to find a [hack](https://github.com/voyagermesh/voyager/issues/1296), which seems that it worked for some users in their use case, you can try that by leaving your code in yaml like,

```
  readinessProbe:
     httpGet:
       path: "/"
       port: 3000
       scheme: "HTTP"
     initialDelaySeconds: 30
     periodSeconds: 15
```

Even though I was not able to find an error on your deploy, the error could be directed to your credentials, so validate the route that you put in Rails and the permissions it has and identify if these change depending on whether it is in production or development environment.

as a last option would be to clarify your suspicions with the Rails app, because I don't see what affects when changing the environment variable to Production.